# Applying different permissions to files vs. directories

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, chmod

Sunny answered the question above in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/104804/chmod-applying-different-permissions-for-files-vs-directories/104805#104805), The answer was given as

> No need for scripts.
>
> // Directories:
>
> ```
> find . -type d -exec chmod XXX {} \;
> ```
>
> // Files:
>
> ```
> find . -type f -exec chmod XXX {} \;
> ```

Can you please explain this in layman language?

I really dislike unexplained `{}` and `\` markup and don't care much for the `;` either!

I've been trying to learn Linux cli / bash / shell whatever and googling etc., to find answers and on the most part it's working well, except when the above happens.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [`find(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) manpage?

Comment: It's nice for an answer to be educative but it's (arguably unfortunately) not required. Asking a new question in a Q/A site (as you did) is the right way to deal with this but you shouldn't get mad over it.

Answer (score 4):

The `{}` is a placeholder that represents the files that find matches. This is how you tell the command that is passed to the exec argument what files find matched.

The `;` terminates the command being used for the exec argument. The `\` is just to escape the `;` so it isn't parsed by the executing shell (`;` is normally used to separate multiple commands to be executed sequentially). You could just as easily quote it in some other manner:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod XXX '{} ;'
find . -type f -exec chmod XXX '{} ;'
```

You could also alternatively use a + instead of a ;. This will cause find to append each match to a list and pass them all to one sub-process (instead of spawning a new child process to run the command in the exec argument on each match). (Note: if you have a very large number of matches, using + could result in you getting an error about the command being too long).

```
find . -type d -exec chmod XXX {} +
find . -type f -exec chmod XXX {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

`.` = the current directory, ie. search the current directory and any directories below it.  To search home-directories, use `/home`.  To search your home-directory, use `~/`.  To search the directory of user "foo", use `~foo/`.  To search *everything* from the root downwards, use `/`.

*NB!:* Permissions apply!  If you don't have the right to decend into a certain directory (like the home-directory of another user), then `find` can't do it either!  The *root*-user don't have such stupid limitation, but "with great power comes great responsibility" too.

`-type d|f` = Tells find to look at files of a certain "type", eg. file, directory, socket, symbolic-link, named-pipe, ... .  A `f` specifies that the type you're looking for is a file, while a `d` specify that you want `find` to return directories.

Usually `find` will just list the files it finds, this is the implicit `-print` directive.  Here however, we want find to execute a command (here `chmod`) on the files/directories it finds.  To do so, we can use the `-exec` or `-ok` directives.  `-ok` will first ask you "yes" or "no" before executing it's command.

The command to be executed, starts right after `-exec` and continues until `find` encounters a `;` (semicolon).  Unfortunately, the semicolon has special meaning to the shell too (`bash` and others) - it's used by the shell to group commands together on one line (eg. `command1 ; command2`).  So we must "quote" the semicolon so that the shell doesn't "see" it before `find`.  The shell accept three forms of quoting:  Double ("...") and single ('...') quotes are typically used for strings - we could use either to quote the semicolon.  However, when you want to quote just a single character like here, it's more common to use the third form of quoting - a backslash (\).  The result it the `\;`.  (If you put your `find`-command in a file - ie. makes a script - you can often forego the `\;` and just use the `;`, because the shell doesn't expand a script the same way it does the command-line.)

Often the command we want `find` to execute will need the filename `find` has found.  `{}` is used as placeholders for the filename found.  Often it's a good idea to put the placeholder in quotes - `"{}"` - to make sure filenames containing spaces are treated as a single filename by the command.

For files I've found that `chmod u=rw,go=r {}` or `chmod u=rw,go= {}` works best, while directories should used `chmod u=rwx,go=rx {}` or `chmod u=rwx,go= {}` (depending on your level of paranoia).

Answer (score 1):

> I really dislike unexplained {} and \ markup and don't care much for the ; either!

In the alternative, if the {} and \; are overly troublesome, there is an alternative approach. In addition, this approach handles spaces in the file name better than the find ... -exec formulation.

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod MASK
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod MASK
```

The -print0 to the find command creates a list of null terminated strings. The xargs processes the list, with the -0 indicating it must split on the null terminated string.

In addition, in some situations, this formulation is faster than the -exec argument to the find command. There is some discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896808/find-exec-cmd-vs-xargs

It is also possible the -print0 is Linux only, as opposed to Unix generally.

Answer (score 0):

Let me throw in a few bits about the `\;`:

The delimiter `\;` for the `-exec` command, will make `find` start a new process for each found file. Now imagine running this on a directory tree with a few 100,000 files ...

If you run commands like `chmod XXX ...` which can handle /many/ files in one run, you will fare much better with

```
find <base> <conditions> -exec chmod xxx {} +
```

`+` lets find build up larger command lines, dramatically reducing the number of processes that need to be launched. Also, it does not need a `\` :-)

Comment: I believe only GNU `find` supports `+`.

Comment: OP tagged /linux, so ... Honest question: Do we have linux systems around without GNU find?